# Flutter in app subscription migrating from Play Billing

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, revenuecat

I'm switching from Java to Flutter.
My actual Java app has about 100 subscribed users and I can't keep their subscription in Flutter using the official in_app_purchase plugin because it doesn't support the verification.

I'm looking for a solution so I found RevenueCat.
It seems the most preferred choice but I don't have the app_user_id required for the [data migration](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/migrating-existing-subscriptions#bulk-imports).
The same happens with [Adapty](https://docs.adapty.io/docs/importing-historical-data-to-adapty).

Does someone did it before?

Comment: do you have any sort of login in your app? you could derive an identifier from your login system and set that as app_user_id. It should be a non predictable identifier that identifies a user uniquely. Take a look at this https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/user-ids#tips-for-setting-app-user-ids

Comment: With 100 subscribers, a client-side migration should be pretty painless and doesn't require an app user ID: https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/migrating-existing-subscriptions#client-side-migration

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to make the subscription device-based instead of account-based. Otherwise everyone could share the account login and I will lost subs...